# Coldfusion CFUPLOAD to S3 Permissions Issue - Can't view image

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion

Using Coldfusion, I am successfully able to upload an image to an Amazon S3 bucket and folder. I can confirm that the file is there. This is the code:

```
<cfparam name="attributes.bSubmit" default="" />

<cfif Trim(attributes.bSubmit) NEQ "">
    <cfset local.filePath = "#application.Config.cdnDirAbs#/public/" />
    <cffile action="upload" filefield="tFile" destination="#local.filePath#" nameconflict="makeunique" charset="utf-8" />
    <cfoutput>DONE UPLOAD</cfoutput>
    <cfoutput>
        <img src="#application.Config.staticContentDirAbs#/public/#cffile.clientfile#">
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a File 
    <input type="file" name="tFile" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="bSubmit" />
</form>
```

As you can see, I am uploading an image file to the "public" folder of my Amazon S3 bucket.

That folder "public", has the "READ" permission set for "ALL USERS".

However, when the image is uploaded, it does not inherit this permission.

So when I try and display the image, it doesn't display. When I view it in the browser by its url, it displays xml with the message "AccessDenied".

If I manually set that image/object's permission to READ for ALL USERS and run the page, or view the url again, then it works.

How do I get the uploaded object to inherit the READ permission of its parent folder ("public"). OR alternatively, how can I set the permission of the uploaded image/object after I upload the image?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I have also added an S3 Bucket Policy, which has ALMOST done the job.
Using the policy below, I can now view upload images, and when I right click the image, and select "open image in new tab", I can view it fine too.

HOWEVER, if I copy the image's URL and paste it into a new browser tab and click enter, it still gives an "ACCESSDENIED" error in that one specific scenario. Which is very strange. Any ideas why?

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1380565312345",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1380565312345",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysitedev/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": "*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Quick question, have you written a Bucket Policy? It's a short JSON string that provides default permissions for the bucket.

Comment: @TRose: I have, and have updated the question with the details. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't have filled out the "Condition" part. The reason the file won't open in a brand new tab is because it has no referrer. It shouldn't need one if you want these to be public.

Comment: @TRose: Excellent. I removed the condition clause and that resolved that issue! Thanks a lot. If you'd like to post a copy of the solution as a reply below, I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted answer!

Comment: I mostly just poked your code with a stick, but I will gladly accept that offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially you were missing a complete S3 Bucket Policy, but we hashed that out in the comments.

It appears as though you've set up a Policy using a template from their support page.

One critical error - you filled out the Condition clause, meaning the Bucket will look for reasons to stop the request from going through. In your case, you specified an expected referrer, which means anyone who copied and pasted a direct link in a new tab would have been stopped.

I suspect your code now looks something like this, having removed your Conditions:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1380565312345",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "Stmt1380565312345",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mysitedev/*"
    }]
}
```

And that your Bucket is accepting ALL requests by the public to view that content. Enjoy!